# neural network input shape

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, nlp

consider if my corpus has 5 sentences, where maximum sentence size is 10 words.

Hence, will the embedding matrix be 5x10.

And what will the input shape of the input layer of a neural network, or how the data will be given as input to neural network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first layer in your network will be the embedding one.

The dimension **of the first parameter of your input** will be a number  <= 50 (5 sentences * 10 words).
It can be smaller considering the fact that all the words in your dataset may not be unique.

Therefore, the input layer will be an `Embedding()` layer, with

`input_shape = (number_of_words_in_the_vocabulary, embedding_dimension)`,

where embedding dimension is a hyperparameter you can choose.

You can have a look here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/word_embeddings